# Console show CSP error because chrome extension reload blob file when location change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, github, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I wrote a chrome extension which insert an image on github page, the image's src was created according to a XMLHttpRequest's response (blob type), like this:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let badgeUrl = `https://api.travis-ci.org${project}.svg`;
  xhr.open('GET', badgeUrl, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        const img = $("<img alt='build status'></img>");
        img.attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response));
        img.on('load', () => {
          const link = $(`<a class='travis-ci' href='https://travis-ci.org${project}'></a>`);
          link.append(img);
          link.appendTo($(el));
        });
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
```

It works fine when you land github page at the first time, but if I click tab link to access other page in github (e.g. landing `https://github.com/Username?tab=repositories` from `https://github.com/Username`), I'll get this CSP error on console log:

```
frameworks-506169c….js:4 Refused to load the image 'blob:https://github.com/e6006be0-c503-421b-87a5-46fe8a150d2a' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: assets-cdn.github.com identicons.github.com collector.githubapp.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com *.githubusercontent.com".
```

here is the screenshot:
[sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS4Rb.jpg)

The errors amount equals the number of blob images inserted in previous page.

Actually, it doesn't have impact on the function of this extension, but I am looking forward to make the console more clean without these annoying error log. Anyone has idea on it?

BTW, I already added the link like 'api.travis-ci.org' into `permissions` of manifest file like this:

```
  "permissions": [
    "https://api.travis-ci.org/"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://github.com; object-src 'self'",
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js":      [ "bundle.js"],
    "matches": [ "https://github.com/*" ],
    "run_at":  "document_idle"
  } ]
```

Comment: Write the svg contents in `<svg>` tag just like github itself does.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for this advice, but it seems that it was not related to the the html tag type. But I use another solution to solve this problem: just save these images locally.